# How to wait a finish of the task and its continuation?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I learn to work with the threads on the base of a book.

I want to wait while my task and its continuation are working. But I see the *"Press any key for exit...*" message before "*BLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEP*" (look the comments of my code, please). Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

I know that I can use two tasks and to use `Task.Wait()` for each of them, but what if I need to do the same for *the continuation object*?

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bushman.Sandbox.Threads {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.Title = "Threads";

            try {
                // The main work
                Action act1 = () => {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                        int id = Thread.CurrentThread
                        .ManagedThreadId;

                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "bleep. Thread Id: {0}",
                            id.ToString());
                    }
                };

                // This operation is to be done when the main 
                // work will be finished.
                Action act2 = () => {

                    int id = Thread.CurrentThread
                        .ManagedThreadId;

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "bleep. Thread Id: {0}",
                        id.ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "BLEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEP. Thread Id: {0}",
                            id.ToString());
                };

                Task task = new Task(act1);
                var awaiter = task.GetAwaiter();
                awaiter.OnCompleted(act2);

                Console.WriteLine("Work started...");
                task.Start();

                // TODO: wait while both actions will be done

                task.Wait(); // it doesn't work as I expected

                // it doesn't work as I expected too...
                awaiter.GetResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key for exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine that the `OnCompleted` action gets fired in another thread/task, and as such, there is no guarantee as to whether the `Console.WriteLine` in that thread or in your main thread will fire first.

Comment: Also, looking at the MSDN doc for the [`TaskAwaiter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx) class, it's usage is intended for the compiler, not for the code directly. Why are you using it rather than `task.Wait()`? How does `task.Wait()` not do what you expect?

Comment: @Abion47, you might be interested to read this http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html to understand why it's sometimes preferrable to use GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of Wait().

Comment: @Evk I'm not sure I understand the reasoning. It seems like the only benefit is that it doesn't wrap an exception thrown by the task in an `AggregateException`, but unpacking the exception seems like it's just a matter of convenience (which I can still totally get behind, but still). It also seems like that blog post recommends against using either `TaskAwaiter` _or_ `Task.Wait()`, preferring instead to use `await` in 99.99% of cases (and is not clear as to what part of the 0.01% of cases constitutes not using it).

Comment: @Abion47 sure, if you _can_ use await - you should do it. However there are certain cases where you cannot and you should block (one example is when you require synchronous execution but API you are using only provides asynchronous version, which happens often nowadays). In that case (which do legitemately happen, even if rare) you might prefer GetAwaiter().GetResult() to not bother with AggregateException. There cannot be more than one exception anyway, so no reason to bother with unpacking that one exception from AggregateException. Of course that is a matter of convenience as you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OnCompleted event is triggered on a different thread that you are not waiting for. You could use the following construct:

```
Task task = new Task(act1);
var awaiter = task.ContinueWith(x => act2()).GetAwaiter();
task.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Work started...");

awaiter.GetResult();
```

In this case `act1` will be executed using the first task and when this task is completed it will continue with `act2`. The awaiter in this case will wait for both to complete.

Comment: Thank you. But why I get the same thread id for the task and its continuation? I edited my code and the screen. Look it again, please.

Comment: That's normal, tasks are just a pool of threads and since there's no other thread running after the first task has finished executing, the task scheduler decides to reuse the same thread to execute the second task. If you run the 2 tasks in parallel, rather than waiting for the first to complete before running the second, then you will get different threads. Try running your 2 tasks in parallel to see the difference: `var tasks = new[] { Task.Factory.StartNew(act1), Task.Factory.StartNew(act2) }; Task.WaitAll(tasks);`